# Some Questions About ServiceStack.Redis

Tags: c#, redis

1. Which Proxy is supported? If any, how can i use it?
2. Whether hashtag is supported? Or something like that?
3. Except for unit tests, is there any complete use case? (i.e. Although I read the official GitHub document, I still don't understand how to use it.)

[Official GitHub Docs](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#configure-redis-sentinel-servers)

Answer (score 2):

You're linking to the [Configure Redis Sentinel Servers](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Redis#configure-redis-sentinel-servers) docs so I'm assuming you want to configure your ServiceStack.Redis instance to work with a Redis Sentinel configuration.

Note [Redis Sentinel](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) is Redis's high-availability solution (it's not a proxy), I'd recommend reading the [Redis's official Redis Sentinel docs](https://redis.io/topics/sentinel) to learn about how it works.

First you'll want to setup a Redis Sentinel configuration. A popular setup is to have **1x Redis Master** and **2x Redis replica slaves**, in addition it's common to have a separate redis sentinel instance (which monitors the running redis instances) on each server that's running a redis instance. To make it easy to develop with you can use [ServiceStack's redis-config](https://github.com/ServiceStack/redis-config) project which makes it easy to run **1x master**, **2x slaves** and **3x sentinel** processes on the same server.

Then when you have your Redis configuration running (assuming localhost) you can connect to it using ServiceStack's `RedisSentinel` class by passing in the IP and port of each sentinel instance, e.g:

```
var sentinelHosts = new[]{ 
   "127.0.0.1:26380", 
   "127.0.0.1:26381", 
   "127.0.0.1:26382", 
};
var sentinel = new RedisSentinel(sentinelHosts, masterName: "mymaster");
IRedisClientsManager redisManager = sentinel.Start();
```

> Note: you don't have to include the IP and ports for Redis master or Redis slave instances as they'll be automatically discovered and can even change. You also can start with a single Redis Sentinel Instance as `RedisSentinel` will also be able to discover other sentinels in the same `"mymaster"` group.

Once you call `sentinel.Start()` it will return a configured `IRedisClientsManager` which maintains a pool of open Redis client connections as well as listening to Redis's sentinel server instances for any changes to the Redis Sentinel Configuration, e.g. in-case the Redis master falls over to one of the running slave replicas.

You should maintain the `redisManager` as a singleton and use it to resolve all redis clients you need, e.g. if using an IOC you can register it as a singleton:

```
container.Register<IRedisClientsManager>(redisManager);
```

Whenever you need to connect with Redis you can use `GetClient()` to resolve an redis connection with the current master instance:

```
using (var redis = redisManager.GetClient())
{
}
```

And the end of the using statement (or when calling `.Dispose()`) your open Redis connection will be returned to the internal connection pool, awaiting for the next time it's resolved.